# jquery show/hide next ul

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, show-hide

I have a problem with show/hide `ul` element in this sample. my jquery script work on any element except `ul` elemeny

```js
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).next('ul').hide();
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
  <span class="menu-text"> Link </span>
</a>

<b class="arrow"></b>
<ul class="submenu nav-show" style="display:block">
  <li class="">1</li>
  <li class="">3</li>
  <li class="">4</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8kouunk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because next will only target the immediate next sibling, which is b tag in your case.

You need to target the first element from nextAll ul siblings:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
 $(this).nextAll('ul:first').hide();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rg1w1f03/)**

If you want to toggle the ul element then use `.toggle()` instead of `.hide()` above:

```
$(this).nextAll('ul:first').toggle();
```

**[Demo with toggle effect](http://jsfiddle.net/sfcjhryo/)**

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```js
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).siblings('ul').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
  <span class="menu-text"> Link </span>
</a>

<b class="arrow"></b>
<ul class="submenu nav-show" style="display:block">
  <li class="">1</li>
  <li class="">3</li>
  <li class="">4</li>
</ul>
```

or as milind said it will work on next ul element only so second option

```
$(this).next().next('ul').hide();
```

and for toggle

```js
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
  <span class="menu-text"> Link </span>
</a>

<b class="arrow"></b>
<ul class="submenu nav-show" style="display:block">
  <li class="">1</li>
  <li class="">3</li>
  <li class="">4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/c8kouunk/2/

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(event) {

 $(this).parents('body').find('ul').hide();
});
```